# using Middleware in Laravel for Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions, laravel-middleware

this code is used as middleware in laravel, to just allows to user who has a spicific permission to do something, and it is working, but really i don't understand how does it work?
can anyone please explain this code line by line?

this code for Middleware called (AuthGates)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            //add all permission 
            if ($user) {
                $roles            = Role::with('permissions')->get();
                $permissionsArray = [];
    
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                foreach ($role->permissions as $permissions) {
                    $permissionsArray[$permissions->title][] = $role->id;
                }
            }

            foreach ($permissionsArray as $title => $roles) {
                Gate::define($title, function ($user) use ($roles) {
                    return count(array_intersect($user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray(), $roles)) > 0;
                });
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

and then called this class in Kernal:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
 

   'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        AuthGates::class
    ],
```

after that use it in the blade.php file to show a link for example just for who has this permission like (work_access) permission:

```
@can('work_access')
link here or any html parts we want to protect.....
@endcan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\AuthGates::class,
```